# Can't install perl 5.14.2 with perlbrew

Tags: perl, installation, perlbrew

I am on a virtual machine with Debian (6.0.7-i386) and i want to learn Perl (with Beginning Perl written by Curtis Poe).

I have trouble with `perlbrew`.

1. I installed `perlbrew` with

   ```
   wget --no-check-certificate -O - http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
   ```
2. I add the following command to `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
   ```
3. After that, I logged out and logged back, and then I ran the following command:

   ```
   perlbrew install perl-5.14.2
   ```

I got

[image]

Please help me

---

English translation of the output:

```
tar (child): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/bin/tar: Child returned status 2
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: BTW, you may also want to install the most recent version of Perl (`perlbrew install perl-5.20.0`) which has some interesting new features. (But perl-5.14 is fine, too).

Comment: I will try when i finish the book :) thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's failing because the `bzip2` command line utility isn't installed (can't be found in the PATH).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ikegami, it was that.

I did this

```
aptitude install bzip2
```

and now it's working.